# How can I get a Post with XML-RPC in Wordpress?

Tags: php, web-services, wordpress, xml-rpc

After some digging around with the [Wordpress XML-RPC documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp), it seems that there isn't a way to remotely obtain a "post" (such as a news article) through the XML-RPC interface.  The documentation only mentions wp.getPage - if I try and pass in a PostID to this method, it returns:

```
 [faultCode] => 404 [faultString] => Sorry, no such page.
```

... but wp.GetPage obviously does work when I pass a valid PageID.  Does anyone have any ideas how I might go about solving this?  Ideally, without extending the XML-RPC mechanism on the remote site (as access to these could be tricky)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure this out.  You can do this by using the "blogger.getPost" method. There isn't much documentation for this on the Wordpress site, but if you check out xmlrpc.php in the root of the Wordpress directory you will find a complete list of XML-RPC functions, including:

```
        // Blogger API
        'blogger.getUsersBlogs' => 'this:blogger_getUsersBlogs',
        'blogger.getUserInfo' => 'this:blogger_getUserInfo',
        'blogger.getPost' => 'this:blogger_getPost',
        'blogger.getRecentPosts' => 'this:blogger_getRecentPosts',
        'blogger.getTemplate' => 'this:blogger_getTemplate',
        'blogger.setTemplate' => 'this:blogger_setTemplate',
        'blogger.newPost' => 'this:blogger_newPost',
        'blogger.editPost' => 'this:blogger_editPost',
        'blogger.deletePost' => 'this:blogger_deletePost',
```

Hope this helps anyone who struggles with this in future.

Comment: How to access word press data from a android app.I know there are methods like wp.getPosts,wp.getUser ,but my problem is how to utilise it in my android code.pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

Check this site out. It explains the Blogger API, and the parameters that each method consumes:

http://xmlrpc.free-conversant.com/docs/bloggerAPI#newPost

Answer (score 0):

I relocated [**elWpAPI** to its own domain](http://www.wpremotecontrol.com/). And improved it a lot, including media uploads and **full WordPress 3.2.1 compatibility** of both the [Core API and the rFC/rSQL plugin](http://www.wpremotecontrol.com/snippets/). *Just saying*... ;)

*And the morally incompatible browser 'error' is gone. Failed forcing people into minimal privacy defense mode.*

Answer (score -1):

See:

[Wordpress XMLRPC API | Remote Control Wordpress](http://blog.5ubliminal.com/posts/remote-control-wordpress-blog-xmlrpc-api/)

Comment: Thanks - i'll take a look.  (on a side note: that site reports I have a morally incompatible browser! [Chrome in OSX] http://desmond.yfrog.com/Himg526/scaled.php?tn=0&server=526&filename=screenshot20100621at092.png&xsize=640&ysize=640)

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to be a paid plugin.  Looking for something free really.

Comment: Commercial/paid software and 3rd party links are generally bad news as an answer. This is a link not an answer. This one of course turned into a 404. Which almost always happens as well. -1